# Increase row count in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm developing an address book for my classmates but I'm having a problem with a `JTable`. Here you can see a preview of the program, I'm using NetBeans [[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9etL9.png)]. If you click `Add to the Address Book`, the program adds a new row in that table and fills its cells with the data located in text fields below. I'm using the following code but the row count doesn't increase.

[image: GUI as is]

```
 private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        int h;
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
        h=jTable1.getRowCount()+1;
        model.setRowCount(h);
        jTable1.setValueAt(jTextField2.getText(), h, 1);
        jTable1.setValueAt(jTextField3.getText(), h, 2); 
        //I'll use more setValueAt() because I must fill all the cells
    }
```

Could you give me some advice as to how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You created a new model. You should take the model that is assigned to the table.

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
```

should be:

```
DefaultTableModel model = jTable1.getModel();
```

Comment: Thank you, now I understand my mistake :) I'd like ask you another thing: I'm using `jTable1.setValueAt(jTextField3.getText(), h, 2);` this method to add datas into cells. By the way, the program doesn't add the content of jTextField3. Do you have an idea about this?

Comment: @DK64 try to use `DefaultTableModel.addRow` method.